# Path not found after fileupload

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, file-upload

In java using tomcat for my server I am able to upload a file to a directory correctly using file-upload commons I can verify the file is in the directory, but then when I go to access the path, I cannot see it until I restart the server. How do I fix this? I have tried a few things I seen in searches like adding a context entry to no avail.

Comment: access path http://ipaddress:8080/Instance/uploads/myfile.pdf
does exist and opens on C:\workbench\instance\WebContext\uploads\myfile.pdf

Comment: Can you look at D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\webapps\ROOT\uploads\myfile.pdf or D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\webapps\---your-webapp---\uploads\myfile.pdf ?

Comment: C:\TOMCAT\webapps\Instance\InstanceFiles is empty... is this where I should be actually saving the files to access them? I am using eclipse so I looked at the working path eclipse had as my default place to save them.

Comment: That also goes for C:\TOMCAT\webapps\Instance\ is empty as well.

Comment: In eclipse is a developpement ONLY. Eclipse need F5 to take into account. You need search a production solution.

Comment: Well the problem still stands even if I drop the file in the other directory I am not seeing it. I created a different folder there and I don't seem to be able to even list the root of that directory. (I turned on listings to help debug the issue)

Comment: pl store your file at other place (not in tomcat directory) , because after restarting server all the file created at run time ,it will be lost.

Comment: It does not seem to matter where I store it. Even after setting the context it does not appear in the listing nor is it accessible until after I restart the server. That is the issue.